# SD Card (Sandisk SDHC) not responding for CMD9 with 0x00 in SPI mode and it responds with time out error 0xFF

Tags: sd

I am trying to interface Sandisk SDHC micro sd card of 8GB size with MSP430FR5969. I am able to initialize the SD card correctly in SPI mode. But When I try to read CSD with CMD9 it responds with 0xFF time out error. It is not responding with 0x00 (R1 response in SPI mode). Please help.

Comment: Consider marking an answer accepted if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved it. We have to send 2 bytes of dummy characters before the CMD9 command. I sent only 1. Problem resolved